# How to filtering complex json file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filter

[image]

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log(data.Jobs[0].Job.Settings.Inputs[0].FileInput)
           ftr = data.Jobs
           rslt = ftr.filter(function(element){
             return element.Job.Settings.Inputs[0].Fileinput == 's3://transvideo-source71e471f1-knewdmajkw29/assets01/Pexels Videos 2219383.mp4';

            });
```

i want to get one array element by fitering the object type data(use JSON.parse(data))

i can't get filtered element and just get below error message

```
Error [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'Settings' of undefined
```

how to i can  get  filtered data by using 'Fileinput'(element.Job.Settings.Inputs[0].Fileinput)

Comment: Example data as CODE would be useful. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering `data.Jobs`, which is an array of `Job`. But then, you are trying to access `element.Job` another time. In other words, you are trying to access `Job.Job`, that's why it's undefined.

```
const rslt = data.Jobs.filter( Job => Job.Settings.Inputs[0].Fileinput == 's3://...2219383.mp4');
```

Comment: ok thanks for you cool Answer and i understand the reason of error. but i still get error message` Error [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'Inputs' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rslt = data.Jobs.filter( Job => Job.Settings.Inputs[0].Fileinput == 's3://...2219383.mp4');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.